# Issues with mypy

Tags: python, mypy

I am trying to use mypy for static type checking in my python project. However, I am seeing the following errors when running mypy,

```
utils.py:15: error: Name 'google' is not defined
```

The annotation is something like this

```
# type: () -> google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2.Timestamp
```

Comment: Well, you can do static type checking, but then it's not Python anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `google` isn't imported in the file, so mypy cannot find it.

Also, if you are working with protobufs and mypy, you might be interested in https://github.com/dropbox/mypy-protobuf, which will automatically generate stubs from protobufs.